# XAMPP for Linux not starting MySQL

Tags: xampp

If I type in terminal

```
sudo ./lampp startmysql
```

I get message:

```
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!
```

I also tried wtih panel

```
sudo ./lampp panel
```

There it says that Apache and PROFTPD are both running but MySQL is stopped. If I try to run it in XAMPP Control Panel I get the following error in console:

```
/opt/lampp/lampp: line 252: echo: write error: Broken pipe
/opt/lampp/lampp: line 257: echo: write error: Broken pipe
```

What is the problem and how could I run MySQL? Restarting XAMPP doesn't work. Please help

Comment: Have you set the permissions on the `/opt/lampp` directory correctly?  It appears like something is trying to write to a log file, but doesn't have the permission to do so.